# mvn build fail when testng test fail

Tags: java, maven, automation, testng

i have 2 different tests

```
public class testcase1 {

        @Test
        public void testcase1() {
            System.out.println("test1 ");
        }
       @Test
        public void testcase2() {
            System.out.println("test 2 ");
        }
       @Test
        public void testcase3() {
             Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
```

when i use `mvn clean test` in terminal its execute all testcases and i git the report but its mark as build fail

here is the log

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.588 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] fail1.testcase2.testcase2  Time elapsed: 0.012 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: did not expect to find [true] but found [false]
        at fail1.testcase2.testcase2(testcase2.java:10)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   testcase2.testcase2:10 did not expect to find [true] but found [false]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  59.248 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-02T07:30:00+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) on project neeewdev1: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/neeewdev1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

please some can you explain why when testng result fail build also fail? and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this option -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore

Comment: It will always pass then

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to test the app not build it. Anyway, if you really want to build it and skip test, you should run

`mvn clean install -DskipTest`

Comment: if its build fail its ok?

Comment: if build fails, then you need to check for any compilation error. The only difference now is that it won't run your test when you build

Answer (score 3):

The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build lifecycle to execute the unit tests of an application

either you can skip the test or if you still want to build the project even if there are test failures then you can use  `**<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>**` in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
     <configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```